# CSS: border gets cut off by the scroll bar

Tags: html, css

My CSS:

```
.ConnectionBox:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: #solid 5px #000;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="ConnectionBox" style="width:600px;height:350px;font-size: 12px; padding-left: 5px; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;border-radius: 5px;border:1px solid #000; overflow-y: auto; text-align: left;">
Blablabla
Blablabla
Blablabla
</div>
```

The border gets cut off on the right side (look at the right top and right bottom side), here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbu8dvLx/) link, how can I fix that?
[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using on what OS?
Doesn't happen to me in Firefox on MacOSX.

Comment: It's due to fact that you have rounded corners. So you need to set some margin from the scrollbar to the right border or reduce the height of the scrollbar.

Comment: Google Chrome v46 on linux

Comment: you have an issue here: `border: #solid 5px #000;` remove the `#` from `solid`, plus it might fix your issue if you add this to your CSS `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: @D3myon how can I do that? I'm new to css

Comment: I would recommend to wrap it inside another container. You can set the requested border here and set some padding.
Have a look at the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4y2g3kjv/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/Lbu8dvLx/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="ConnectionBox">
    <div class="box-content">
        <ul>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
            <li>CPU Model : MIPS 24Kc V7.4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ConnectionBox{
      height:300px;
      width:450px;
      border-radius:10px; 
      border:2px solid #666;
      padding:6px 0px;
      background:#ccc;
    }

    .box-content{
      height:300px;
      width:450px;
      overflow:auto;
      border-radius:8px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to the container with the scrollbar.
The value for the padding should at least be what you gave as the border-radius. That way you ensure that none of the contents will overlap with the border being rounded.

That being said I can't guarantee this to work across all browsers as scrollbars are browser chrome and cannot be affected with CSS.

For example:

```
.element {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Seems this is an OS related problem as the scrollbar in MacOS browsers behaves very differently than compared to the look of Linux.